# I am learning about callback functions and API

Tags: node.js, callback

Here I am learning about Callback functions and API to make weather app on node but when I am running the app on Terminal it says undefined I don't know why?

```
const request = require("request");

request({
URL: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia",
json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Try logging `error` and `response` as well and post those here if you still need help. Please also post a link to the `request` library you are using as it's hard to guess what the callback's signature might be without knowing what library you are using.

Comment: I tried body and response and the result was undefined on terminal and when I tried error it says operation.uri is a required argument. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request  I've install request package today so it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `request` incorrectly. You need to call it like so:

```
request("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia", {
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body);
});
```

**alternatively**

```
request({
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia",
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body);
});
```

**Notice the `url` property in lowercase, whereas yours was uppercase**

Refer to https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

Comment: It feels embarrassing!